# The meaning of Linux Kernel bug output

Tags: kernel, bugs

I have a quick, (maybe naive),question about Linux kernel's output. When I issue a command, the system (Ubuntu 12.04) freezes, the serial port output of this system is as follows:

```
[  373.805067] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 23s! [migration/1:14]
[  373.805069] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 23s! [migration/2:19]
[  373.805070] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#3 stuck for 23s! [migration/3:24]
```

My question is:

What does `[migration/1:14]` mean?

I know 1 stands for the CPU#1, but I'm confused at the meaning of `14`.

Answer (score 0):

Processes identified as `[...]` are threads that run inside the kernel. Without looking too much closer, something gets stuck when migrating tasks from one CPU core to the other. This is a serious kernel problem (as you see, the machine get stuck).

If not LTS, upgrade to the latest Ubuntu. If LTS, update all, and consider upgrading. If the problem persists, collect *all* relevant data (exact machine model, CPU model, kernel version) and report it at the relevant Ubuntu bugtracker.

Comment: Hi, @vonbrand, thank you very much for your explain! Actually, I knew that. But I don't understand the meaning of 14 in the `[...]`.  This may not be a problem of Ubuntu, because I'm hot-plugging cpus for the OS. As you pointed out, a kernel thread is migrating tasks from one cpu to anther, but the problem is how I can know which one it is migrating to?